# Calling random function inside another function

Tags: c++, function, random

I have function which genrenate me random index like this :

```
size_t randomIndex(vector<int>myVector) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    size_t index1 = rand() % myVector.size();
    return index1; 
}
```

I call it inside another funtion :

```
void generaTwoIndex(vector<int> myVector2) {
     size_t index1 = randomIndex(myVector2); 
     cout << "index1 = " << index1 << endl; 
     size_t index2 = randomIndex(myVector2);
     cout << "index2 = " << index2 << endl;
}
```

It generate me the same index. What is the issue ? 
Thank's in advance for your answers.

Comment: ***What is the issue ?*** You are calling `srand(time(NULL));` in too soon which most likely causes the same seed (because the number of seconds did not change - although even if it did this would be wrong). My advice is to seed 1 time in your `main()`.

Comment: No ! it don't call it in the loop. In the seconde function  I want to generate two different index  randomly using the first function.

Comment: ***No ! it don't call it in the loop.*** It is the same reason though.

Comment: It not the same think. In my case I dont use the loop http://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%cf%80%ce%ac%ce%bd%cf%84%ce%b1-%e1%bf%a5%ce%b5%e1%bf%96

Comment: ***It not the same think.*** It is. Think of your case as unrolling a loop of size 2. With that said read the answers below. They all explain the cause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`time(NULL)` returns the time in seconds since 1970.  Since you call the function twice an a row, way less than a second passes between invocations, so `time(NULL)` returns the same value for both calls, and the RNG is seeded with the same value for both calls.

When a random number is generated, the generator is automatically seeded with its result.  So you only need to seed it once:

```
size_t randomIndex(vector<int>myVector) {
    size_t index1 = rand() % myVector.size();
    return index1; 
}

void generaTwoIndex(vector<int> myVector2) {
    srand(time(NULL));    //I would recommend moving this line to main()
    size_t index1 = randomIndex(myVector2); 
    cout << "index1 = " << index1 << endl; 
    size_t index2 = randomIndex(myVector2);
    cout << "index2 = " << index2 << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`srand()` was created to make `rand()` deterministic, so what is probably happening is that because the two calls to `srand()` are called at almost the same time they get the same value for `time(null)`, which determines future values of `rand()`.  To fix this, change the second block to this:

```
void generaTwoIndex(vector<int> myVector2) {
     srand(time(NULL));
     size_t index1 = randomIndex(myVector2); 
     cout << "index1 = " << index1 << endl; 
     size_t index2 = randomIndex(myVector2);
     cout << "index2 = " << index2 << endl;
}
```

and remove `srand(time(NULL));` from the first block.